# Pspell don't work

Tags: php, apache, php-7, linux-mint, pspell

Please, help me with pspell problem. I have installed aspell and I have done following comands in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libpspell-dev 
sudo apt-get install php7.0-pspell
sudo apt-get install aspell-en
```

My os is linux Mint 17. PHP - 7.0.28. When i try to use function-checker it return me empty array. But i know definetly that it works correct in hosting. Code of function:

```
function fixMistakeInQString($string, $lang){
    $pspell_config = pspell_config_create($lang);
    pspell_config_mode($pspell_config, PSPELL_FAST);
    $pspell_link = pspell_new_config($pspell_config);


    if (!pspell_check($pspell_link, $string)) {
        $result = pspell_suggest($pspell_link, $string);
        foreach ($result as $key => $value){
            if(preg_match('~\s~ui', $value) || preg_match('~-~ui', $value)){
                unset($result[$key]);
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }else{
        return array($string);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have only tried with PHP8.1, but like this it runs smoothly on my system.
Install the dependencies (e.g. for Ubuntu):

```
sudo apt install aspell
sudo apt install php8.1-pspell
sudo apt install aspell-en
```

or Alpine:

```
apk add aspell aspell-en php81-pspell
```

then you can run in PHP:

```
<?php
$pspell = \pspell_new("en", null, null, "utf-8", PSPELL_FAST);
if (!\pspell_check($pspell, $word)) {
    $suggesstion = \pspell_suggest($pspell, $word);
}
```

Make sure to give it your phrase word by word, it can not handle sentences or unusual sequences.